# How to convert hex strings to a meaningful data in order of ml based classification?

Tags: python, tcp, classification, random-forest

I have some hex strings which are represent tcp packet payload. the payloads are encrypted using TLS and I want to find a pattern for it. The problem is tcp packet classification just by using tcp payload and for that reason I used `le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()` for `KNN` classification in order to change hex string of payload to a value. The result was 5% accuracy in classification I changed the classification to `Random Forest` but the result was just like before. What is your solution for encrypted payload based classification?

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['payload'] = le.fit_transform(df['payload'])
one_hot_encoded_data = pd.get_dummies(df, columns = ['class'])
print(one_hot_encoded_data)

X = one_hot_encoded_data.iloc[:, one_hot_encoded_data.columns != 'class_1']
y = one_hot_encoded_data.class_1

#-----------------------------------------


x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.6, random_state = 0)

model4 = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0).fit(x_train, y_train)
print ('Random_Forest_train_accuracy:', model4.score(x_train, y_train))
print ('Random_Forest_test_accuracy:', model4.score(x_test, y_test))
y_pred4 = model4.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: I am not a cryptographer, but I thought that after encryption, the data is often _randomly_ distributed over the field where the encryption function is defined,  which is one of the reasons why you cannot traceback the original data from the encrypted data. Of course, heuristics exists, but, unless you know the original key, you'll always have a lower accuracy.

Comment: @cmbfast is it possible to define a statistical model e.g. Gaussian and represent it with its first,second,... statistical order?

Comment: sounds like you're trying to do [p-hacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging). Steffen's answer below explains really well on why doing this may not give you any meaningful results.

Answer (score 0):

Using (properly) encrypted content as a feature for machine learning makes no sense. A main property of proper encryption is that there is no statistically significant relation between original content and encrypted content. The statistic properties of encrypted content are similar to random data instead and thus provide absolutely no value as a feature in machine learning.

There are a few information which can be used though, like

- size of encrypted payload which is similar to the size of original payload but not not exactly the same
- timing and direction of data, which also reflect the timing and direction of the original data
- some meta information from the TLS handshake, like server name (SNI), certificate information (up to TLS 1.2), TLS client fingerprint ([JA3](https://github.com/salesforce/ja3)), chosen cipher ...

There are actually [lots of publications](https://www.google.com/search?q=machine+learning+encrypted+traffic) about this topic.